# Can you make the circle into a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

I thought maybe use a set with elements of the form $e^{i\theta}$ but what field would the scalars be taken from? Multiplying $ke^{i\theta}$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ doesn't give you another point on the circle though, so what field is used?

Comment: Trivial solution: Let $f$ be a bijection from the circle to the real line. Define addition and scalar multiplication on the circle via $x+y=f^{-1}\big(f(x)+f(y)\big)$, $ax = f^{-1}\big(af(x)\big)$. Done.

Comment: @Rahul, how do you find a bijection between the circle and the real line that respects order?  One is compact; the other is not.

Comment: @Sammy: Who said anything about order?

Comment: @user132074: the short answer to your question is probably "no", not in any meaningful way that preserves the structure that you consider a circle.  As Rahul demonstrates, if you're willing to drop enough structure, you can make anything into a vector space.  Without knowing what your motivation is, it's hard to give a better answer.

Comment: (nitpick: you can't make a vector space out of a finite set whose size is not a prime power) (double nitpick: I suppose you could if "which specific objects are elements of the set" is part of the structure you drop)

Answer (score -1):

For the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, call it $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:x^{2}+y^{2}=1\}$ is not a vector space. Indeed, the two vectors $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ lie in $S$. We will show that the sum of these two vectors do not lie in $S$. From this, we can therefore conclude that $S$ is not a vetor space, as it will not be closed under addition. So since $(1,0)+(-1,0)=(0,0)$ and $(0,0) \notin S$, this finishes the proof.

Here is a question to contemplate. If one adjoins the zero vector $(0,0)$ to $S$, is $S \cup \{(0,0)\}$ a vector space?

Comment: It still is not, under your definition of $+$. Consider $(1,0) + (1,0)$.

Comment: @Rene: maybe you can think of the vector space _generated_ by the circle, i.e., the smallest vector space containing $S^1$; it is not $S^1 \cup (0,0) $.